# Match a word starts and ends with different letter

Tags: regex

I am writing a general expression to match words that start and end with different letters.

I tried `^(.).*(?![^\1]$)`. But it doesn't work.

Some words to test: "`aa`", "`ab`", "`aba`","`aab`","`abc`".

Comment: Can you be more specific? Mention input, output, expected/correct output and incorrect output

Comment: Why you need regex here, just compare first and last character. `str[0] !== str[str.length-1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put a backreference inside a character set - instead, before the last character, negative lookahead for the first group (no character set), then match any character and the end of the string:

```
^(.).*(?!\1).$
```

https://regex101.com/r/fnpsgf/1

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your definition of "word" (which character is allowed)

```
\b(\w)\w*(?!\1)\w\b
```

This first regex will identify all the words that meet the criteria (first word char different than last word char in the word (and word `length>=2`)) from a sentence.

If you use `.` in your regex it will match any character (except for line terminators), this include spaces...

You can replace it by ^(\w)\w*(?!\1)\w$ if your input is already a word, also change `\w` (equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) by a more suitable range for you or a predefined character class (depending on your regex engine `\p{L}`, `[[:Alpha:]]`, `\p{Alpha}`,...).